# How to select BLOB files in PHP using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have 50 images stored in SQL Database (BLOB). How can i select it and show it as an image in a view.

I have tried something like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $pics = DB::table('Employees')->get();
    return $pics; //just to test if i get something return from the db
    //return view('welcome', compact("pics"));

});
```

When i return the db query i get a very long string for an image.

```
FFD8FFE1001845786966000049492A00080000000000000000000000FFEC00114475636B7900010004000000500000FFE1031D687....
```

I have tried something like this with `base64_encode` in my view:

```
  @foreach ($pics as $pic)

        <img src="base64_encode({{ $pic->image }})" />

  @endforeach
```

unfortunately this is not working and i don't know how to encode it and return it as a path for the `img` attribute `src`.

Comment: can you show the code how you save the image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the hex value to string, then encode the string by base64.

To convert the hex value to string:

```
$string = pack('H*', 'FFD8FFE1001845786966000049492A00080000000000000000000000FFEC00114475636B7900010004000000500000FFE1031D687');
```

Then encode the string by base64

```
$string = base64_encode($string);
```

Then you can use [Data URI schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to display the image. Base on the [file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), the hex string you given is jpg image. You should also change the mime type accordingly.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?=$string?>" />
```