# Laravel. Retrieve Image from SQLSERVER. Datatype: image

Tags: sql-server, laravel, image, blob

I'm trying to retrieve an image from SQLServer and show it in the browser, but it´s not working. Could anybody help me?

1. Controller

   ```
   public function viewFamily(){
      $queryPhoto = IDF_FOTO::select('FOT_BLO_IMG_FOTO')->where('ID_PROCESSO', '123456')->get();
      $image = $queryPhoto[0]->FOT_BLO_IMG_FOTO; 
      echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $image ) .'" height="100" width="100"/>';
      echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ' . chunk_split(base64_encode($image)) .'" height="150" width="150"/>';


      return view("intel.viewFamily", ['queryPhoto'=> $queryPhoto[0]]);    }
   ```
2. Result on Browser:

   [image]

I really appreciate any help to solve this.
Thank you!

Comment: Why did you save your image to your database?

Comment: Hi Jesus. It wasn't me. Unfortunately, this is the way they do it here in my workplace. We can´t modify this policy.

Comment: The image datatype has been deprecated for nearly 15 years now in favor of varbinary(max). And storing images directly in the database is a real pain to deal with.

Comment: Yes, I aggree with you, Sean. I would change the DB if I could, but I'm really tied to that rule...

Comment: I agree with you guys, plus that can take more storage, slowdown the SQL queries and its hard to share the images to other parties if you have that features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution in another topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47756897/6157142 .
Need to convert the HEX to String, then encode it by base64.

```
$queryPhoto = IDF_FOTO::select('FOT_BLO_IMG_FOTO')->where('ID_PROCESSO', '123456')->get();
    $string = pack('H*', $queryPhoto[0]->FOT_BLO_IMG_FOTO);
    $string = base64_encode($string);
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$string.'" />';
```

Worked fine to me.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to upload the image again to the storage? Thank you